# GLX on macOS using multipass and ubuntu as guest

Tags: 20.04, multipass

I'm running macOS Ventura 13.5.1 with multipass 1.12.2+mac. I'm trying to run glxgears on a Ubuntu Focal guest under multipass. I've already activated indirect GLX on the XQuartz (2.8.1) using

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_iglx -bool true
```

However, I still get the error

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears
libGL: MESA-LOADER: dlopen(/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so)
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/ubuntu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/ubuntu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Disabling server's aux buffer support
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: glXCreateContext failed
```

Any ideas whether it is possible to use GLX and how to do it?